# How exactly am I supposed to gain enough reputation to make a comment?

Tags: support

From my understanding you gain rep from :

1. Asking questions
2. Answering questions
3. Receiving upvotes from other users on your comments or answers.

Many of the questions I see here are answered by veteran career pilots / aviation related engineers.

I am just an early 20's economics student with a passion for planes and most things aviation related, it's highly unlikely I am going to be able to answer in anywhere near as much detail or in such a concise manner as the vets already on here.

However on my occasions when I see an answer where I'd like to post a comment for some clarification on specific parts of an otherwise great answer, I obviously can't since I lack 50 reputation.

So to repeat my initial question ;

If I don't have any questions to ask, and I am completely out-educated by many of the current answer-posters on this site, how am I meant to build rep?

Comment: Is there an SE site where your expertise counts? If you've earned I believe 200 on an SE site, you get 100 bonus points on any other SE site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the simple option of finding some questions to ask. The easiest way is to read other questions and when the answers are confusing ask about what was confusing you. They may not be "high quality" questions but they should get you the reputation you need.

Comment: Fair enough. Theres always that thin line between just needing a small clarification and requiring a whole new thread to be created for a question, but there really is no other way on this stackexchange.

Comment: @Ksery well, I haven't checked the details but building enough reputation on another SE gives you a 100 signing bonus when you join a new stack. I don't know if it works retroactively. (On mobile annoying to check.)

Answer (score 5):

> when I see an answer where I'd like to post a comment for some clarification on specific parts

and

> I don't have any questions to ask

These two statements don't fit together. If you want to comment on an answer to ask some follow-up questions, then you have a question! It's perfectly OK to ask a question that links to another question or answer for its background. "I read *this answer* but didn't understand *this aspect*. What's going on there?" can be a good question. Better yet, asking it as a question means that everyone will see it and can try to answer - not just the author of the original answer. Maybe the original answer was vague on a couple of points because it's outside the author's area of expertise, or they just don't know how to explain it well. Maybe it was brief because an explanation that a newbie would understand is too long to fit in an answer where it's not the main point.

The thing about new users not being able to make comments is a bit of a nuisance, but the original intent was for exactly this reason: so that new users who don't realise their comment should be a question or answer, won't post comments and lose out. New users often think that posting a question is somehow expensive or there's some kind of minimum size for a question, but questions can be as small or straightforward as you like.

One last side point is that you don't need to know everything to answer. You might read some answers by high-rep users and assume they're just answering from experience, but I've posted a lot of answers where I didn't know anything about it before the question was posted. I saw the question, was intrigued, and researched it myself, finding out enough information on my own to post a good answer. Experience isn't the main variable in how good your answers can be: it's the willingness to research and put effort into writing a complete answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Taking the advice of @BStein I tried to ask a few questions I had to myself when flying recently and low and behold my question was downvoted (not entirely sure why). So  I think i'll just move back to an observer point of view for now until my questions become... 'worthy?'.

Comment: I saw your downvoted question, and it was very much about commercial air travel from a passenger point-of-view, which is off-topic on this site. And it did read a little hysterical.

Comment: Fair enough I guess, I guess I should research the entire range of different stack exchange sites. Also it wasn't really a prevalent question I had, it was simply a question I was asking in an attempt to gain some rep, following the advice of one of the other answers in this thread. Also I was asking it from more of a technical point of view.

Comment: Top tip.  Don't try to chase or ["farm" rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126987/what-is-rep-farming).  It usually doesn't go well and experienced stackers can spot it a mile off.  Just follow the advice given and wait a little while.